# The correct way to direct domain URL to Codeigniter controller

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I wanted to find out what is the correct way to direct my domain URL to my Codeigniter index controller. So for example my domain name is `www.example.com` and my CI index controller is at `www.example.com/code1/index.php/index`.

Should I use `.htaccess rewrite` rules to redirect or Codeigniter url mapping?
What would the rules look like?

Thanks!

Comment: have reconfigured your route.php, the one in `default_controller`..that will set the default loaded controller/action of your application.

Comment: Do you have multiple sites/apps in www.example.com? If you were going to rewrite to make it appear `code1` isn't there, the rewrite would need to be sitting in www.example.com/.htaccess. Easier way to do it would be to have a single domain per app, if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that just by using CI route mapping, You need to use .htaccess and it could be like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ code1/index.php/$1 [L]
```